# Shell Script Not Finding File

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, backup

Hello I am trying to write a simple shell script to use in a cronjob to copy a backup archive of website files to a remote server via FTP.

The script below works when I type the file name in by hand manually, but with the date and filename specified as a variable it returns that it can't find ".tar.gz" as if it is ignoring the first part of the filename.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me where I am going wrong.

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=$(date +"%F")
FILE="$NOW_website_files.tar.gz"

# set the local backup dir
cd "/home/localserver/backup_files/"

# login to remote server

ftp -n "**HOST HIDDEN**" <<END
user "**USER HIDDEN**" "**PASSWORD HIDDEN**"
cd "/backup_files"
put $FILE
quit
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because it is looking for a variable name `NOW_website_files` which does not exist, and thus the resulting file name evaluates to `.tar.gz`.

To solve it, do:

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=$(date +"%F")
FILE="${NOW}_website_files.tar.gz"
       ^   ^
```

instead of

```
FILE="$NOW_website_files.tar.gz"
```

This way it will concatenate the variable `$NEW` to the `_website_files.tar.gz` text.

Comment: To be more precise, it's actually looking for a variable named ``NOW_website_files`` (``_`` is a valid character for a variable name) which does not exist, and thus the resulting file name evaluates to ``.tar.gz``, explaining the error message the OP is seeing.

Comment: Completely right, updated my answer with your very clear explanation, @YS-L . Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, still quite to new to shell scripting so this had me completely lost as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
FILE=$(date +"%F_website_files.tar.gz")
```

instead of this:

```
NOW=$(date +"%F")
FILE="$NOW_website_files.tar.gz"
```

**IMPORTANT**

By the way, consider adding "bi" to your FTP script as you are clealy PUTting a binary file and you don't want CR/LF translation to occur in binary files...

Comment: Thanks, I was using PHP originally to backup the website archive, however it kept running out of memory, so had to turn to shell scripting as a solution which I am not familiar with.